# How do I fix this snippet in swift 4?

Tags: swift4

I'm trying to add text attributes to a draw method in Swift 4:

```
let textFontAttributes = [
            NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue: font,
            NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: minuteTickColor,
            NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: textStyle
        ] as! [String : Any]

.....

var numberString:NSString = String(index) as NSString
numberString.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
```

This doesn't compile, and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The compile error is:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type '[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]?'
```

Solved (still testing)

```
let textFontAttributes = [
                NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue: font,
                NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: minuteTickColor,
                NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: textStyle
                ] as [AnyHashable : Any]

....

numberString.draw(at: point, withAttributes: textFontAttributes as! [NSAttributedStringKey : Any])
```

Comment: idk... try __not to__ downcast `textFontAttributes` to something forcibly what you cannot use later...?

Comment: hmm. Could you please expand.. I cant see what I should be doing.. Thanks

Comment: so... what is that then `... as! [String : Any]`?

Comment: got it. I'm updating my question.

Comment: Why do you need `.rawValue`?  Without it, type inference does a lot of the work for you so the `as [AnyHashable : Any]` and `as! [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]` can go away.

Comment: Thanks. I'd better slow down and look at this some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let textFontAttributes = [
     NSFontAttributeName: font,
     NSForegroundColorAttributeName: minuteTickColor,
     NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: textStyle
]
```